# Creating a link in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to make all cells of a column, in my JQgrid, a link, which calls a javascript function with the cell value, to be passed for some query on the server side. I have seen [html link column in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166076/html-link-column-in-jqgrid)
but it is not working out. here is what I have,

```
colModel:[
{name:'name',width:300,formatter:link}
]
```

and the link function is

```
function link(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {


alert('<a href="javascript:logForProv(\''+cellvalue+'\',\''+$('#datepicker1').val()+'\',\''+$('#datepicker2').val()+'\');">');
return "<a href='javascript:logForProv(\''+cellvalue+'\',\''+$('#datepicker1').val()+'\',\''+$('#datepicker2').val()+'\');'>";
        }
```

Doing this I dont get any data in the column, I also tried using the predefined formatters link and showlink, but they are appending href and id to the URL which is messing up.

Please Help.

Comment: can you post the code for `logForProv` function?

Comment: The function makes an ajax call, it was working fine when I was not using jqgrid and appending the link directly to a table, the problem has to be outside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When click on `providerId` edit column you will redirect to edit page of `editProvider`.
mention`formatter: editLink` at `providerId` colModel for call `editLink` function. In this way creating link in jqGrid.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //jqGrid
        $("#providerList").jqGrid({
            url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getProvidersList',
            datatype: "json",               
            colNames:['Id','Edit','Provider Name'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'providerId',search:false,index:'providerId',hidden:true},
                {name:'providerId',search:false,index:'providerId', width:30,sortable: false, formatter: editLink},
                {name:'providerName',index:'providerName', width:200},
                rowNum:20,
                rowList:[10,20,30,40,50],
                rownumbers: true,  
                pager: '#pagerDiv',
                sortname: 'providerName',  
                viewrecords: true,  
                sortorder: "desc",  
        }); 
        $('#gridContainer div:not(.ui-jqgrid-titlebar)').width("100%");
        $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('height', window.innerHeight * .65);
        $('#load_providerList').width("130");   
        $("#providerList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDiv',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},{},{},{}, {closeAfterSearch:true});
        $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"20%"});
    });
    function editLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action)
    {
        return "<a href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Admin/editProvider/" + rowdata.providerId + "' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' ></a>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `logForProv` have to be defined **on global (top) level**.

I recommend you to try better `formatter: "dynamicLink"` instead, which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935) and which you can download from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins) (`jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js` file). It allows to construct link in jqGrid in very simple and flexible way. You can define `onClick` callback inside of `formatoptions` (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DynamicLink.htm)). The callback provide `rowId`, `iRow`, `iCol`, `cellValue` and `e` as parameters.

Comment: Thank You, your answers are very well written, I solved the problem using a function inside a formatter that returned the anchor ,which worked , without using link and showlink, Why do you say the function needs to be on a global level though, is it a good practice ?

Comment: @SKaul: You are welcome! If you use JavaScript function in `href` then the function *have to be defined as global*. It's better to reduce the usage of global function of cause. You wrote that your original code not worked. I supposed that you have defined `logForProv` not on as global (not on the the top level).