# Redirecting the JQgrid after editing row

Tags: jsp, struts2, jqgrid

How to redirect after editing the JQgrid data redirect it to some other page for adding some additional info regarding the row edited I am using jsp with Struts2 framework.

Answer (score 0):

You simply call the user defiend function `editLink` in `colModel` and you can pass the `id` of the edited record in editLink function.

Here is the answer of your question [How to navigate to another page when click on edit in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21754150)

Comment: I have to redirect to next page only in case of the valid input is provided by user not in all case.

Comment: @amandeepsingh then check if else condition in `editLink` function.